# jenkins npm or node not found tried the plugin jenkins suders

Tags: serverless-framework

npm: command not found it is unable to find node or npm in Jenkins user

[

```
xxxxx-build-pipeline] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins7546525206314731997.sh
Whoami
jenkins
/tmp/jenkins7546525206314731997.sh: line 4: node: command not found
/tmp/jenkins7546525206314731997.sh: line 5: npm: command not found
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ncc-do/xxxxxxx-pipeline
/tmp/jenkins7546525206314731997.sh: line 9: serverless: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: This command may be doing literally anything. For example execute `node` and `npm` commands on a different machine. Please provide at least broad description of the script, ideally describing key details.

Comment: This is next to unanswerable as we have no clue what the '/tmp/jenkins7546525206314731997.sh' script wants to do. Moreover, assuming the script is correct, we have no knowledge of the installed software on the machine and/or the user's settings such as the PATH, nor of the settigns to PATH done inside the script.

Comment: have installed node and npm as sudo user in the jenkins build machine but when i just do a npm or node version it says node or npm not found